# SE calculation for proportions using "survey" package in R

Tags: r, survey, proportions

I am analysing data using the survey package.

There is a function `svyciprop` that allows for CI calculation but I am trying to find a proper way to calculate standard errors for proportions.
Only two things worked until now, using `SE(svyciprop(formula, design))` or `svymean(formula,design)`, both calculations display the same SE result, are they proper ways to calculate SE for proportions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they calculate the standard error for the proportion.  The standard error isn't always that useful for proportions, because you often want an asymmetric confidence interval such as the ones `svyciprop` computes.  But if you do want the standard error, that is how to get it.